# API version implementation in RESTEasy3.0.7 in JAVA

Tags: java, resteasy

I am trying to implement API version in REST Easy 3.0.7 in java. After reading many article on api versioning i conclude that best approach is sending version number in header. Currently I am receiving api-version parameter in header as `api-version:1.0` in class i have to methods like..

```
@GET
@Path("/status/test")
@Produces("application/xml")
@Consumes("application/json")
public String test()
{
    return "Test OK";
}
```

and

```
@GET
@Path("/status/test")
@Produces("application/xml")
@Consumes("application/json")
public String test1()
{
    return "Test OK - 2";
}
```

Here I want to keep the path same as it is like /status/test but based on version i want to select method test or test1 like if `api-version:1.0` then method test and if `api-version:1.1` then method test1 should be called.

Please suggest a way that how can i achieve this functionality if i receive the versions in header?

Comment: Why does your `@GET` method consume something?

Comment: Hi lefloh, I have just added to add Content-Type:application/v-1.1 to add versioning support. In this case consume will become @Consumes("application/v-1.1").. I was just trying different way to add versioning support.. if you think this is not a good way then i can drop it..

Comment: `@Consumes` defines the accepted MediaType of the entity passed in the payload of the request. `GET` doesn't have a payload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it by having one method calling `test()` or `test1()` depending on the version:

Something like :

```java
@GET
@Path("/status/test")
@Produces("application/xml")
@Consumes("application/json")
public String testFacade(@HeaderParam("api-version") String version)
{
    if(version.equals("1.0") return test();
    else return test1(); 
}

private String test()
{
    return "Test OK";
}

private String test1()
{
    return "Test OK - 2";
}
```

[See Documentation for HeaderParam](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.7.Final/userguide/html_single/#_HeaderParam)

Comment: Can we not achieve this functionality using annotation? I can see there are many annotations available.. may be one of them works.

Comment: @AbdulBasit there is no annotation that I know of that could discriminate based on header (be it in JAX-RS or RestEasy). There is always the possibility to make your own.

Comment: Do you have any idea or if there is any other way to implement this thing then please guide me. Actually i want to avoid if else or function switch mechanism.

Comment: @AbdulBasit I don't have any other reasonnable idea. But why don't you want to use if? If you're allergic, you can always use reflexion to get the method base on api-version but it is a _little_ overkill, I think.